# Javascript onclick not executing after reopening a page

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am using alpha anywhere, I have a frame that contains several fields in it. I can toggle- show/hide the content using this:

```
document.getElementById('minim').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('icon-minim').classList.toggle("fa-plus");
document.getElementById('content-minim').classList.toggle("closed");
```

My problem is the toggle wont work after I reopen the page. not until I refresh the whole window. It works as long I did not close the page.
I have tried the `window.onload` but no luck. the result is the same. As I say, only works after I refresh the whole page. my thought was, the `id` is still in use, thus the toggle fail or I need to reset the `div`'s state before I toggle. but still I don't know how to accomplish that.
Your help is very much appreciate.

This is the html:

```
    <div class="A5ControlBarLineContentAfter">&#8203;
          <div class="A5ControlBarItem" style="">
            <button id="minim" type="button" class="button" style="width: 98%;margin-right: 20px;overflow:auto;" title="" a5-item="bodyAdj" onmouseover="if(!this.disabled){$acn(this,'buttonHover');}" onmouseout="$rcn(this,'buttonHover');if($ga(this,'a5-pressed') != 'true'){ $rcn(this,'buttonPressed');if(!this.disabled || '' == '') A5.u.icon.update($('DLG1.V.R1.CONTROLBAR_1.bodyAdj.ICON'),'cssIcon=fa fa-plus');
              else A5.u.icon.update($('DLG1.V.R1.CONTROLBAR_1.bodyAdj.ICON'),'');}">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" id="icon-minim" style="; vertical-align: middle; border: none;"></i>
            </button>
          </div>

        </div>
  <div id="content-minim" class="window-body window-hidden" style="width: 100%;margin-right: 20px;overflow:auto;">
    <div class="window-content">
      {grid.Search_Part}
    </div>
```

Comment: You are looking for id="minim"  but it doesn't exist in your html !!!!

Comment: My bad. I forget to edit that part. I copy the first code section into another page and forget to rename the `id`. still the problem not solved.